# Can't start Appium due to apkanalyzer abscence

Tags: android, shell, batch-file, apk, appium

I'm trying to automate some tasks in mobile apps, I decided to use Appium (on Windows) for my purposes.
I added Environment variables (ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME), then I ran appium-doctor to check all dependencies, this is the output

```
info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies starting ### 
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE 
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 18.12.0 
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: C:\Users\Ksenya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk 
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19 info 
AppiumDoctor    Checking adb, android, emulator, apkanalyzer.bat info 
AppiumDoctor      'adb' is in C:\Users\Ksenya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe 
info AppiumDoctor      'android' is in C:\Users\Ksenya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\android.bat 
info AppiumDoctor      'emulator' is in C:\Users\Ksenya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\emulator.exe 
WARN AppiumDoctor  ✖ apkanalyzer.bat could NOT be found in C:\Users\Ksenya\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk! 
info AppiumDoctor  ✔ 'bin' subfolder exists under 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19' 
info AppiumDoctor 
### Diagnostic for necessary dependencies completed, one fix needed. ###
```

I don't know what is apkanalyzer.bat, I red in docs that it is included in Android SDK, but I haven't got it.

In my \Sdk\tools\bin folder I found apkanalyzer file without extension, looks like a bash script, defenetly not .bat

I tried to find info about it, apkanalyzer seems to be a unix script which isn't valid on Windows systems

```
\#!/usr/bin/env sh

\##############################################################################

## 

## apkanalyzer start up script for UN\*X

## 

\##############################################################################

# Attempt to set APP_HOME

# Resolve links: $0 may be a link

PRG="$0"

# Need this for relative symlinks.

while \[ -h "$PRG" \] ; do
ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
if expr "$link" : '/.\*' \> /dev/null; then
PRG="$link"
else
PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`"/$link"
fi
done
SAVED="`pwd`"
cd "`dirname \"$PRG\"`/.." \>/dev/null
APP_HOME="`pwd -P`"
cd "$SAVED" \>/dev/null

APP_NAME="apkanalyzer"
APP_BASE_NAME=`basename "$0"`

# Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and APKANALYZER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.

DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'

# Use the maximum available, or set MAX_FD != -1 to use that value.

MAX_FD="maximum"

warn () {
echo "$\*"
}

die () {
echo
echo "$\*"
echo
exit 1
}

# OS specific support (must be 'true' or 'false').

cygwin=false
msys=false
darwin=false
nonstop=false
case "`uname`" in
CYGWIN\* )
cygwin=true
;;
Darwin\* )
darwin=true
;;
MINGW\* )
msys=true
;;
NONSTOP\* )
nonstop=true
;;
esac

CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/dvlib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/util-2.2.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jimfs-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-13.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/ddmlib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/repository-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/sdk-common-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.1.3-2.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/protobuf-java-3.0.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/apkanalyzer-cli.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/gson-2.3.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpcore-4.2.5.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/dexlib2-2.2.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-compress-1.12.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/generator.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/error_prone_annotations-2.0.18.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/kxml2-2.3.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpmime-4.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-12.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.56.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jsr305-3.0.0.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/explainer.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/builder-model-3.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/baksmali-2.2.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/j2objc-annotations-1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/layoutlib-api-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jcommander-1.64.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/annotations-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/builder-test-api-3.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/animal-sniffer-annotations-1.14.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.56.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/httpclient-4.2.6.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/common-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/jopt-simple-4.9.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/sdklib-26.0.0-dev.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/apkanalyzer.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/shared.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/binary-resources.jar:$APP_HOME/lib/guava-22.0.jar

# Determine the Java command to use to start the JVM.

if \[ -n "$JAVA_HOME" \] ; then
if \[ -x "$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java" \] ; then
\# IBM's JDK on AIX uses strange locations for the executables
JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/jre/sh/java"
else
JAVACMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
if \[ ! -x "$JAVACMD" \] ; then
die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: $JAVA_HOME

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi
else
JAVACMD="java"
which java \>/dev/null 2\>&1 || die "ERROR: JAVA_HOME is not set and no 'java' command could be found in your PATH.

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation."
fi

# Increase the maximum file descriptors if we can.

if \[ "$cygwin" = "false" -a "$darwin" = "false" -a "$nonstop" = "false" \] ; then
MAX_FD_LIMIT=`ulimit -H -n`
if \[ $? -eq 0 \] ; then
if \[ "$MAX_FD" = "maximum" -o "$MAX_FD" = "max" \] ; then
MAX_FD="$MAX_FD_LIMIT"
fi
ulimit -n $MAX_FD
if \[ $? -ne 0 \] ; then
warn "Could not set maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD"
fi
else
warn "Could not query maximum file descriptor limit: $MAX_FD_LIMIT"
fi
fi

# For Darwin, add options to specify how the application appears in the dock

if $darwin; then
GRADLE_OPTS="$GRADLE_OPTS "-Xdock:name=$APP_NAME" "-Xdock:icon=$APP_HOME/media/gradle.icns""
fi

# For Cygwin, switch paths to Windows format before running java

if $cygwin ; then
APP_HOME=`cygpath --path --mixed "$APP_HOME"`
CLASSPATH=`cygpath --path --mixed "$CLASSPATH"`
JAVACMD=`cygpath --unix "$JAVACMD"`

    # We build the pattern for arguments to be converted via cygpath
    ROOTDIRSRAW=`find -L / -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d 2>/dev/null`
    SEP=""
    for dir in $ROOTDIRSRAW ; do
        ROOTDIRS="$ROOTDIRS$SEP$dir"
        SEP="|"
    done
    OURCYGPATTERN="(^($ROOTDIRS))"
    # Add a user-defined pattern to the cygpath arguments
    if [ "$GRADLE_CYGPATTERN" != "" ] ; then
        OURCYGPATTERN="$OURCYGPATTERN|($GRADLE_CYGPATTERN)"
    fi
    # Now convert the arguments - kludge to limit ourselves to /bin/sh
    i=0
    for arg in "$@" ; do
        CHECK=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "$OURCYGPATTERN" -`
        CHECK2=`echo "$arg"|egrep -c "^-"`                                 ### Determine if an option
    
        if [ $CHECK -ne 0 ] && [ $CHECK2 -eq 0 ] ; then                    ### Added a condition
            eval `echo args$i`=`cygpath --path --ignore --mixed "$arg"`
        else
            eval `echo args$i`="\"$arg\""
        fi
        i=$((i+1))
    done
    case $i in
        (0) set -- ;;
        (1) set -- "$args0" ;;
        (2) set -- "$args0" "$args1" ;;
        (3) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" ;;
        (4) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" ;;
        (5) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" ;;
        (6) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" ;;
        (7) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" ;;
        (8) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" ;;
        (9) set -- "$args0" "$args1" "$args2" "$args3" "$args4" "$args5" "$args6" "$args7" "$args8" ;;
    esac

fi

# Escape application args

save () {
for i do printf %s\\n "$i" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;$s/$/' \\\\/" ; done
echo " "
}
APP_ARGS=$(save "$@")

# Collect all arguments for the java command, following the shell quoting and substitution rules

eval set -- $DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS $APKANALYZER_OPTS -classpath ""$CLASSPATH"" com.android.tools.apk.analyzer.ApkAnalyzerCli "$APP_ARGS"

# by default we should be in the correct project dir, but when run from Finder on Mac, the cwd is wrong

if \[ "$(uname)" = "Darwin" \] && \[ "$HOME" = "$PWD" \]; then
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
fi

exec "$JAVACMD" "$@"\
```

What can I do with my problem, Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apkanalyzer) apkanalyzer is included in the Android SDK Command-Line Tools package at `android_sdk/cmdline-tools/version/bin/apkanalyzer`. Alternatively, you can access the APK Analyzer tool within Android Studio as described in Analyze your build with APK Analyzer.

Can you please check if there is an apkanalyzer.bat in your case. If not, I would suggest downloading the SDK command line tools once again.

Hope that helps